# How to retrieve data from the firebase and show inside the CardView nicely

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have created the CreateEvent.java module to upload the data to firebase. But how to retrieve the data and show in the Cardlist? For example show in the xml file below. And also if there was more than 1 data in firebase, how to show in with multiple cardlist that I have created in the xml file?

**CreateEvent.java**

```
package com.example.edward.eventmanagementsystem.ManageEvent;
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.example.edward.eventmanagementsystem.R;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.OnProgressListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import static android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;


public class CreateEvent extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "activity_create_event";
    private Uri filePath;
    private TextView mDisplayDate;
    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
    private Button mRegisterButton;
    EditText mEventNameText, mContactNumText, mEventLocationText;
    TextView mEventDate;
    RadioGroup mEventType;
    FirebaseStorage storage;
    StorageReference storageRef,imageRef;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    UploadTask uploadTask;
    Uri uriImage = Uri.parse("com.example.edward.eventmanagementsystem.ManageEvent/"+ R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
    public static final int PICK_IMAGE = 1;
    ImageView mimageToUpload;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
        mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("ListEventInformation").push();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_event);
        mRegisterButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRegisterEvent);
        storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        storageRef = storage.getReference();

        mDisplayDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.RegisterEventStartDate);
        mDisplayDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(
                        CreateEvent.this,
                        android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_MinWidth,
                        mDateSetListener,
                        year, month, day);
                dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                dialog.show();
            }
        });

        mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
                month = month + 1;
                Log.d(TAG, "onDateSet: date: mm/dd/yyyy: " + month + "/" + day + "/" + year);

                String date = month +  "/"  + day + "/" + year;
                mDisplayDate.setText(date);
            }
        };

        //perform action upload image
        mimageToUpload = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageToUpload);

        //insert data to database
        mEventNameText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.RegisterEventName);
        mContactNumText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.RegisterContactNumber);
        mEventDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.RegisterEventStartDate);
        mEventType =  (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.RegisterEventRadiogroup);
        mEventLocationText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.RegisterEventLocation);
        mimageToUpload = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageToUpload);
        mRegisterButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegisterEvent);

        mimageToUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(CreateEvent.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    selectPdf();
                }
                else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(CreateEvent.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},9);
                }
            }
        });

        mRegisterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int selectedId = mEventType.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton)findViewById(selectedId);

                final String name = mEventNameText.getText().toString().trim();
                final String contact = mContactNumText.getText().toString().trim();
                final String date = mEventDate.getText().toString().trim();
                final String type = radioButton.getText().toString().trim();
                final String location = mEventLocationText.getText().toString().trim();

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
                    mEventNameText.setError("Enter First Name!");
                    return;
                }


                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(date)) {
                    mEventDate.setError("Enter Date!");
                    return;
                }


                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(type)) {
                    radioButton.setError("Enter Phone Number!");
                    return;
                }
                if(isValidPhone(contact)){

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Phone number is valid",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else {
                    mContactNumText.setError("Phone number is not valid");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Phone number is not valid",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }


                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(location)) {
                    mEventLocationText.setError("Enter Location!");
                    return;
                }

                Map userInfo = new HashMap();
                userInfo.put("mEventNameText", name);
                userInfo.put("mContactNumText", contact);
                userInfo.put("mEventDate", date);
                userInfo.put("radioButton", type);
                userInfo.put("mEventLocationText", location);

                mDatabaseReference.updateChildren(userInfo);
                final String fileName = System.currentTimeMillis()+"";

                if(uriImage != null) {
                    StorageReference storageReference = storage.getReference();
                    storageReference.child("profileImageUrl").child(fileName).putFile(uriImage)
                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                                    String url = taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl().toString();
                                    mDatabaseReference.child("profileImageUrl").setValue(url).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {


                                            if (task.isSuccessful()){ }
                                            else{

                                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"File not Successfully Uploaded",LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"File not Successfully Uploaded",LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                        }
                    });
                }else{


                }

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"New event created successfully!",LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent ManageEventMenu =  new Intent(CreateEvent.this, com.example.edward.eventmanagementsystem.ManageEvent.ManageEventMenu.class);
            startActivity(ManageEventMenu);


            }
        });
    }

    public boolean isValidPhone(CharSequence phone) {
        boolean check=false;
        if(!Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z]+", phone))
        {
            if(phone.length() < 10 || phone.length() > 11)
            {
                check = false;
            }
            else
            {
                check = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            check=false;
        }
        return check;
    }

    private void selectPdf() {

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        startActivityForResult(intent,86);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == 86 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){

            final Uri imageUri = data.getData();
            uriImage = imageUri;
            mimageToUpload.setImageURI(uriImage);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please select file", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to show the data in this way.
The sample of xml file I would like to display the data create from Firebase in upload from CreateEvent.java

**activity_list_of_event.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/gradientwallpaper">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Events"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Total Created Event"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Upcoming"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Pass"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:weightSum="10">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/item_month"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"

                    android:text="Month" />/                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/item_date"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"

                    android:text="Date" />/                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"

            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/item_eventName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Event Name"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />/android:textScaleX="18sp"

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/item_contactNumber"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Contact Number"

                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/item_type"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Type of event"

                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/itemLocation"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Location"

                    android:textStyle="bold" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/item_image"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/pic1" />


        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i'd suggest you to learn `RecyclerView` first.. ref: https://medium.com/@droidbyme/android-cardview-with-recyclerview-90cfeda6a4d4

Comment: But don't know why every time I use the recycle view in my xml file， my preview part interface will dim...seem like not support or i missing something